# Proof of finance when entering the Ukraine as a German citizen

Tags: proof-of-funds, ukraine, german-citizens, evidence

I am planing a trip to Ukraine and read about a proof of finance as an entry restriction for foreigners. The website of the german [Auswärtiges Amt](http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/DE/Laenderinformationen/00-SiHi/UkraineSicherheit.html?nn=338496#doc338438bodyText4) is mentioning that since 2013 every non ukrainian citizen visiting Ukraine has to verify that she/he has an income of 2300€ a month or at least 80€ per day in Ukraine + 400€.
I would like to know how and how strict these conditions are checked when visiting Ukraine (I am german citizen).

Comment: what's your country of citizenship?

Comment: @JonathanReez I am german. Added to the Question.

Comment: The website that you referring to actually has the answer: The "Auswärtiges Amt" does not have any experience on how these rules are actually implemented in practice. Since the rules are 1.5 years old, this tells you that they are almost never enforced. Also, the list of suitable documents even counts tickets, hotel reservations, and credit cards. I would take a printout of my account statement just to be on the very safe side. Finally, you don't need an income of 2300€ but rather 2300€ per month of stay (according to the page). That's quite a big difference for most travellers.

Comment: I never heard of solvency check at Ukrainian ports of entry. Not breaking 90-day rule with a visa-free travel is important, but not the financial part: you are highly unlikely to be ever asked about funds for your travel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was in the Ukraine in May traveling on a Western European passport.

Upon entry, not a single question was asked. Not even purpose of visit or which regions I would visit. I simply got stamped in and that was that.

Based on this experience, I assume that it is not generally enforced and rarely checked. Probably they start asking this kind of things only when some red flags are raised. I was not even aware of the requirement and did not have the documentation on me to prove my financial situation.

Comment: Summer 2014, USA passport, same experience. Don't think the border guard said a word.

Comment: Turned out that it is exactly like this. Not a single question was asked.